# Calculating a z-score

Tags: standard-deviation

The 2006 Statistical Abstract of the United States reports on a survey that asked a national
sample of 80,000 American households about pet ownership. Suppose that one-third of
all American households own a pet cat. The survey discovered that 31.6% of all the households sampled owned a pet cat. What is the z-score of this?

From the standard deviation formula for a sample proportion, I found that standard deviation is `0.0016`. From there, I plugged that into the z-score formula, and got `(0.316-0.333)/0.0016 = -10.625`. However, a z-score that high baffles me and I cannot imagine getting a z-score that high. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations are correct. The extreme $z$ score you get indicates that if the percentage of households was really $33$%, then this sample is highly unrepresentative. The conclusion you would therefore draw is that the actual percentage must in reality be lower than $33$%, assuming that the sample is random and representative of the population as a whole.